# Set legend according to line colour using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot as
[image]

Using ggplot, how can I set the legend with two labels only, i.e, red lines with name say "prediction intervals" and blue line with name "fit line"

I used following `R` lines for this

```
dfs <- data.frame("x"=1:50,"fit" = rnorm(50,30,4),"upper"=rnorm(50,30,4)+15, "lower"=rnorm(50,30,4)-15)
df_melt <- reshape2::melt(dfs,id="x")
g <- ggplot(df_melt,aes(x=x,y=value,colour=variable)) + geom_line(linetype=5)
g <- g + scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","red")) 
g <- g +  theme_grey(base_size = 16) + theme(axis.text=element_text(colour = "black",size = 12))
g
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add a new column with 2 values ("prediction intervals" or "fit line")

[image]

```
# Add a new group column 
df_melt$group[df_melt$variable == "fit"] <- "fit line"
df_melt$group[df_melt$variable != "fit"] <- "prediction intervals"

# don't forget `group = variable`
g <- ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = group, group = variable)) +
geom_line(linetype=5)
g <- g + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue" ,"red", "red")) 
g <- g +  theme_grey(base_size = 16) + 
theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12))
g
```